# Dynamically control the number of FormGroups with a FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I'm trying to dynamically control the number of FormGroups with a FormArray such that I set the FormArray length.

```js
myForm = this.fb.group({
  formGroupsToAdd: ['5'],
  formList: this.fb.array(this.getFormControls(5))
});

getFormControls(numberOfFormGroups: number) {
  const myArray = new Array(numberOfFormGroups);
  myArray.fill(this.fb.group({
    length: [''],
    width: [''],
    height: ['']
  }));
  return myArray;
}
```

I also have a way of getting this `formList: FormArray` with

```js
get unitList() {
  return this.myForm.get('formList') as FormArray;
}
```

However, when I go to add a value to a single control in this `FormArray`, it updates all `FormGroup`s in the `FormArray`.

```html
<div formArrayName="formList">
  <div *ngFor="let unitForm of formList.controls; let i = index">
    <div [formGroup]="formList.controls[i]">
      <pre>{{formList.controls[i].value | json}}</pre>
      <pre>i = {{i}}</pre>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="length" />
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="width" />
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="height" />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So my `formList.value` looks like this...

```json
[
  {
    "length": "",
    "width": "asdf",
    "height": ""
  },
  {
    "length": "",
    "width": "asdf",
    "height": ""
  },
  {
    "length": "",
    "width": "asdf",
    "height": ""
  },
  {
    "length": "",
    "width": "asdf",
    "height": ""
  },
  {
    "length": "",
    "width": "asdf",
    "height": ""
  }
]
```

Where instead I need a single `FormGroup` to contain of course it's own unique `FormControl` values.

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the `[formGroup]="formList.controls[i]"` satisfy my need here by providing a unique identifier for each formGroup?

EDIT: I've added a stackblitz with my problem.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sa7pbb?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [formGroupName]="idx" like this.

```
<div formArrayName="formList">
  <div *ngFor="let unitForm of formList.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="length" />
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="width" />
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="height" />
      </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

And some useful functions:

```
// Call init form on init
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();
}

// init form here
initForm() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      formList: this.fb.array([])
    });

    // Call this 5 times or any times you want to init rows.
    this.addItem();
}

// Add new item to make an addition button on UI
addItem() {
    // You can enter input into newItem function to load data from API to make update/details screen.
    this.unitList.push(this.newItem(0, 0, 0));
}

// Your function to get fromList
unitList() {
    return this.myForm.get('formList') as FormArray;
}

// new Item as a FormGroup to add into main form and it will auto render on UI
newItem(length: number, width: number, height: number): FormGroup {
    const newGroup = this.fb.group({
      length: [length],
      width: [width],
      height: [height]
    })
    return newGroup;
}

// Clear all items to make a refresh/clean UI
clearAllList() {
    this.unitList.clear();
}

// Remove item at index to make a delete button
removeItem(index: number) {
    this.unitList.removeAt(idx);
}
```

**Updated:**
Fix issue on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rtmpwc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

The issue is `myArray.fill`, and when you use it, it will use 1 reference variable to set for all 5 items in your array. So when you change one item, it will ref into 5 items

```
getFormControls(numberOfFormGroups) {
    const myArray = new Array(numberOfFormGroups);
    myArray.fill(this.fb.group({
      length: [''],
      width: [''],
      height: ['']
    }));
    return myArray;
  }
```

So the fixed function should be like this. It will create 5 reference for 5 items.

```
getFormControls(numberOfFormGroups) {
    const myArray = new Array();
    for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfFormGroups; i++) {
      let newItem = this.fb.group({ length: [''], width: [''], height: [''] });
      myArray.push(newItem);
    }
    return myArray;
  }
```

Comment: I've added a stackblitz to illustrate my problem.

Comment: did you try the approach mentioned on this answer ?

Comment: Great question @MauricioGraciaGutierrez, yes. I did. It doesn't work.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez I fixed his issue with my solution in stackblitz and he said it's not the issue.

Comment: @gh0st I updated my solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `[formGroupName]="i"` instead of `[formGroup]="formList.controls[i]"`

```html
<div formArrayName="formList">
  <div *ngFor="let unitForm of formList.controls; let i = index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <pre>{{formList.controls[i].value | json}}</pre>
      <pre>i = {{i}}</pre>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="length" />
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="width" />
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="height" />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've added a stackblitz to illustrate my problem.

Comment: did you try the approach mentioned on this answer ?

Comment: Great question @MauricioGraciaGutierrez, yes. I did. It doesn't work.